# insert main check box and sub check box into table

Tags: php, html, sql

i've problem with my code especially about check box. ok, this is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logistic_manager ORDER BY id_lm";
$main = mysql_query($sql);

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($main)) {
  echo " + <input type='checkbox' name='cx[]' value='$r[id_lm]' /><b>$r[logistic_manager]</b><br>";
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM area, logistic_manager WHERE area.id_lm = logistic_manager.id_lm AND area.id_lm = $r[id_lm]";       
  $sub = mysql_query($sql2);
  $jml = mysql_num_rows($sub);
  if($jml > 0) {
    while($w=mysql_fetch_array($sub)){
      echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp - <input type='checkbox' name='cxsub[]' value='$w[id_area]' />$w[area] - $w[id_area]<br>";
    }
  } else { print "<br> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp - Subuser undefined<br>";}
  print "<br>";
}
```

output on html:

```
+ Logistic Manager id-> 1 (selected)
      - A ->id: 5 (selected)
      - B ->id: 9
      - C ->id: 10 (selected)

+ Logistic Manager id-> 2 (selected)
      - D ->id: 6 (selected)

+ Logistic Manager id-> 3 
      - E ->id: 7

+ Logistic Manager id-> 4
      - F ->id: 8
```

sorry, should check box not list..

the question is how do i insert the selected check box into table?
i'm so happy if any one can help this.. thanks before :)

Comment: Why do you query logistic_manager twice?

Comment: ok.. i want to insert main check box n sub check box in to one table. later it will be seen by logistic manager and sub logistic manager. logistic manager can see all of his data based on his id as group and can see all of his sub data based on his id sub too.

Answer (score 0):

checkboxes not displaying...

Untested code:

Line of output we want with names and values surrounded by " marks:

```
+ <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="$r[id_lm]" /><b>$r[logistic_manager]</b><br>
```

One way to get it...

```
echo ' + <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="'. $r[id_lm] .'" /><b>'. $r[logistic_manager] .'</b><br>';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..

i've found the main problem, how to set main check box and sub of main check box on array, like array 1 dimension for main check box and 2 dimension for sub of main check box, through related each other, between main check box and sub check box? so i can be discerning the sub check box is owned by certain main check box..